# Correlation in R; numeric

Tags: r, correlation

I've dealt with R's correlation algorithm before, but I am unsure what is going on with my current code.

My input data are two .csv files. The first only has one column, and I coerced it as a data.frame. It looks like this (my data are quite long time series, so I'm only showing the first 10 data points)):

```
                  trends
         V1    0.2701541
         V2      2.00532
         V3      1.79548
         V4    0.2549123
         V5    0.2124736
         V6    -1.132594
         V7    -0.711875
         V8    -1.577067
         V9   -0.5320426
         V10    1.325005
```

My other files has several columns, and looks as follows:

```
       X13_EVI     X14_EVI     X15_EVI     X18_EVI
1    1.0492437  0.54155557 -0.58480284 -3.47111922
2    1.7274555  1.46141010  0.79416226  1.04050086  
3    1.7274555  1.46141010  0.48772557  1.17721662  
4   -0.1941446 -0.14833532 -0.12514781  0.22020630  
5   -0.1941446 -0.14833532 -0.12514781  0.22020630  
6   -0.5332505 -0.60826258 -0.73802119 -0.73680402 
7   -0.4202152 -0.49328077 -0.12514781 -0.32665674 
8   -0.9853917 -1.29815348 -1.04445787 -0.73680402 
9   -0.3071799 -0.03335350  0.18128888 -0.46337250  
10   0.5971025  1.00148284  1.10059895  0.63035358
```

When I try to do

```
corr=cor(trends, all.obs)
```

I get the error message

```
Error in cor(trends, all.obs) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I can't remember coming across this problem before and am unable to figure out what causes it. In the past I've always been able to calculate the correlation between each observed time series (the columns in all.obs) and the trend (in this case 1 trend). I've checked

```
> is.numeric(trends)
[1] FALSE
> is.numeric(all.obs)
[1] FALSE
> is.data.frame(all.obs)
[1] TRUE
> is.data.frame(trends)
[1] TRUE
```

I also did

```
> typeof(all.obs)
[1] "list"
> typeof(trends)
[1] "list"
```

because I got

```
> trends=as.numeric(trends)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

It's been a while since I worked with this though, so maybe I'm missing something very obvious?

Comment: Try `unlist` to make the list into a vector. If it isn't numeric, convert it to a numeric.

Comment: `cor(cbind(trends,all.obs))` will give you a correlation matrix including the one column in `trends` and all the columns in `all.obs` . That might be the simplest fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to see if all the columns of `trends` and `all.obs` are stored as numeric.

To do it, run `sapply(trends, is.numeric)` and `sapply(all.obs, is.numeric)`. If you see any `FALSE` in the output you should fix it by coercing to numeric with the help of the `as.numeric()` function.

OR, a better way to avoid this kind of problem, is specifying the type of the columns when reading the csv files. You do this by using the `colClasses` parameter from `read.csv` function. Example:

```
trends <- read.csv("PATH_TO_DATA_FOLDER/trends.csv", colClasses = "numeric")
all.obs <- read.csv("PATH_TO_DATA_FOLDER/all_obs.csv", colClasses = rep("numeric", 4))
```

See if it is sufficient.

Comment: Even though the solution offered did not solve the problem, it lead me to the solution, so I'm going to accept it as an answer. By using colClasses (which produced errors, hence some more sleuthing), I figured out there was an "incomplete final line" in the .csv file (this was a file produced by R - so now I've learned that might be an issue!)

Comment: Used colClasses = "numeric", worked like a charm, thank you :-)